# How do I prove that the following expected values are equivalent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution

I have been having difficulties with the following problem:

> Show that if $f(x)$ is bounded and $X\sim\mathrm{Poiss}(\lambda)$ then $\mathbb{E}[\lambda f(X+1)]=\mathbb{E}[Xf(X)]$. Here $\mathrm{Poiss(\lambda)}$ denotes the usual Poisson distribution with pmf $p(k)=e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k/k!$ for $k\geq0$.

From what I could find online, it seems it has something to do with exchangeable pairs and/or Poisson approximation, but I am struggling to get started with the problem. How do I prove that the following expected values are equivalent? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried calculating the expectations more or less explicitly (as sums)?

Comment: So far, I have tried to simplify the LHS. I first pulled out the lamda since it is a constant (I believe). Then I have lamda * E[f(X+1)]. Then I have lamda * Summation[f(X+1)*p(x)]. Is my train of thought correct so far? And is p(x) the pmf?

Comment: $E[f(X)]=\sum_{j=0}^\infty f(j)\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{j}}{j!}$ for any function $f$. Typeset math here using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you for the help and for the link. I'll make sure to format my next questions properly! Also, I tried simplifying the RHS as well and I got lamda*E[f(X)]. So it seems I need to show that E[f(X)]=E[f(X+1)]. I'm a bit confused on what to do with the functions of the random variable in the summations.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda f\left(k+1\right)\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f\left(k\right)\frac{\lambda^{k}}{\left(k-1\right)!}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kf\left(k\right)\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kf\left(k\right)\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}$$

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you! I have one question: what happened to e^-lamda? I thought the pmf for a poisson RV was e^-lamda * lamda^k over k!

Comment: I just left out the factor $e^{-\lambda}$ on both sides because for the explaining of the equality it is irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! This helped me a ton to understand the problem.

Comment: You are very welcome.